# javascript code malfunction when json encode is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

i have a html table and it has expandable row

but when i added json encode code to the javascript code. the html table row expand without the user interaction. when the page is loaded. it just expand. and i need to put the code in a sigle javascript because i need to use the data from other javascript function. hope my question is clear. sorry for my bad english

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
var tracknumberreceiveglobal;
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
            $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
            $("#report tr:first-child").show();

            $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
                tracknumberreceiveglobal =  $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text();
                $(this).next("tr").toggle();
                $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus-sign').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus-sign');
            });

        });



function functiontwo() { 
var tnum = <?php echo json_encode($_tempp1); ?>;
var tsign = <?php echo json_encode($_temppp1); ?>;
var signatoryidglobal = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['signatoryid']); ?>




}
  </script>
```

this is the page looks like without json encode
[image]

this is the page looks like with json encode
[image]

Comment: Where are you using `functiontwo()`?

Comment: We have no way to know what `json_encode` produces or how that UI gets generated or what the differences are between not using json_encode and using it. In short...there is no way for us to reproduce your problem

Comment: Do you need `tnum`, `tsign`, and `signatoridglobal` to be objects for `functiontwo()` to work? It looks like you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP function `json_encode()` returns a string (a JSON representation) and not an actual JavaScript object. You have to parse it in order to make use of the data passed through JSON.

```
var tnum = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($_tempp1); ?>');
var tsign = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($_temppp1); ?>');
var signatoryidglobal = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['signatoryid']); ?>');
```

You can now access properties using dot notation or brackets.